# Como dar um "refresh" após de fazer update do novo vídeo?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, html5, html5-video

Na minha visão, eu tenho um vídeo antigo, quando eu faço "upload" de vídeo novo, 
quero automaticamente recarregar um novo vídeo após de "upload".

Segue o código **View**:

```
<div id="embed_video" class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
    <video class="embed-responsive-item" controls>
        <source src="/Files/GetVideo?id=2" type="video/mp4">
        Seu navegador não suporta vídeo em HTML5.
    </video>
</div>
```

Segue código **Javascript**:

```
 $('#embed_video video').get(0).load();
```

Código do javascript só funciona na primeira vez, na segunda vez o vídeo não atualiza, fica como antigo.

Segue código **Controller**:

```
public ActionResult GetVideo(int id)
{
    using (var ctx = new Entities())
    {
        var result = ctx
            .Video
            .FirstOrDefault();    
        byte[] video_byte = result.Video;    
        return new RangeFileContentResult(video_byte, "video/mp4", "NomeDoArquivo.mp4", date);
    }
}
```

Alguma solução ?

Desde já agredeço.

Comment: Caro Matheus, tinha variaveis erradas no script, adicionei também mais uma checagem, agora creio que o código esteja 100%, se puder atualizar para o nome é melhor.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Sim essa eu vi, não avisei para você.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isto ocorre porque esta em cache, pois provavelmente o nome é o mesmo, uma maneira de resolver é usar uma querystring randômica (o que não se repete, como algo baseado em *timestamp*).

No entanto primeiro é necessário pegar o `currentSrc` (https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/media.html#dom-media-currentsrc), algo como:

```
var videourl = $('#embed_video video').prop("currentSrc");
```

Então limpar a querystring:

```
videourl = videourl.replace(/\?(.*?&)?_=\d+$/, "?$1");
```

E aplicar a nova:

```
videurl = videorl + "_=" + Date.now();
```

Pode fazer uma função assim:

```
function updateVideo(query, play) {
    var el = $(query).get(0); //usei o .get para ficar mais "limpo" o código, mas o resultado é indiferente no final

    if (!el) alert('Não encontrado'); return;

    var videourl = el.currentSrc;

    videourl = videourl.replace(/\?(.*?&)?_=\d+$/, "?$1");
    videourl = videourl + (videourl.indexOf("?") !== - 1 ? "&" : "?");
    videourl = videourl + "_=" + Date.now();

    el.pause();
    el.src = videourl;

    if (play) el.play(); //o play já executa o load
}
```

O uso seria algo como:

```
updateVideo('#embed_video video', true);
```

Ou sem autoplay:

```
updateVideo('#embed_video video', false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Acho que eu respondi essa mesma pergunta ou uma muito semelhante ontem mesmo...
mas segue abaixo:

```
document.getElementById("VideoReload").load();
```

Comment: Já tentei e nada acontece, ele permanece o vídeo antigo.

Comment: Mas se você consultar diretamente a sua action, ela retorna o conteúdo correto?

Comment: Ele funciona só na primeira vez ao chamar `action`, na segunda, terceira etc... nunca chama ação.